# changing date in string data type to java.sql.date data type

Tags: java, date

I have a method which reads the date that in form of srring and then conver it format in dd-MM-yy and finally return a string as shown below..

```
public static String getSimpleDate11(String dateString) {
        if (dateString == null) {
            return null;
        }

        DateFormat dfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        DateFormat dfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");

        try {
            Date date = dfIn.parse(dateString);
            return dfOut.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "The date entered is invalid or has incorrect format"
                            + dateString);
        }
    }
```

now I am calling this method from somewhere as shown below....

```
String formatteddate = DateUtility.getSimpleDate11(settlementDate);
```

now please advise how can I change this in java.sql.Date as I want to store the date in java.sql.Date..

```
java.sql.Date sd ------ here i want tio store the date finally
```

folks ple\ase advise .

Comment: @boxed__l can you please update the code in my post that will help me to grasp Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`java.sql.Date` takes long value in its constructor (irrespective of the date format)

`Date date=dfIn.parse(dateString);`
`new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());`

should be equivalent as they represent the same `Date` object.